Rendering Problem from server to client and client to server
This is main.js where my landing page is render and this is here
let posts = [
    {
        title: "Hello World!",
        content: "Hello World!",
        date: "01klfljs",
    }
];

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs");
});

app.get("/myblog", (req,res) => {
    res.render("myblog.ejs", {
        posts
    });
});

app.post("/myblog", (req,res) => {
    const post = {
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        date: new Date(),
    }
    posts.push(post);
});

This is myblog.js where I want to add this to main.js
const api_url = "http://localhost:3000";

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", async(req,res) => {
    try{
        const {posts} = req.body;
        const response = await axios.get(`${api_url}/myblog`);
        res.render("backend.ejs",{
            posts: response.data,
        });
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(500);
    }
});

This is backend.ejs, where all file will upload, edit
<body>
    <a href="/new">Create a New Post</a>
    <div>
       <ul>
        <% post.forEach(post => {%>
          <li>
            <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
            <h3><%= post.content %></h3>
            <h4><%= post.date %>/h4>
          </li>
          <% }); %>
       </ul>
    </div>

This is myblog.ejs where all file to be shown from backend.js
<body>
    <ul>
        <% posts.forEach(post => { %>
            <li>
                <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
                <h3><%= post.content %></h3>
                <h4><%= post.date %></h4>
            </li>
            <% }); %>
    </ul>
</body>

I want render data from myblog.ejs to backend.ejs
where is the problem ? Thank you for your time, but my problem is I want to get data from myblog.ejs and pass it into backend.ejs, how can I solve this? You can see I am try using posts: response.data but it’s getting me an error when I am using console.log, I see whole entire ejs file is passing into backend.ejs how can I pass only posts data into backend

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Merge myblog.js functionality into main.js. main.js is already set up so extra functionality can be moved from myblog.js into main.js. The variable posts in the app.get("/") route is being extracted from req.body instead of from posts variable or api call. Then use res.redirect("/myblog") after a POST request

Thank you for your time, but my problem is I want to get data from myblog.ejs and pass it into backend.ejs, how can I solve this?  You can see I am try using posts: response.data but it’s getting me an error when I am using console.log, I see whole entire ejs file is passing into backend.ejs how can I pass only posts data into backend
